# Cannot accept answers

Tags: bug, accepted-answer

I have had a few correct answers and been unable to answer them as the tick box is essentially and unclickable link. Upvoting works. Is this a common bug or am I missing something?

It's not an internet timeout or lag as the page stops loading without errors and I have tried it from different access points on different browsers and on different OS (mac windows and Ubuntu). In the source it says `href javascript:void(0);`. This is what I get on mouse hover over also.

I cannot accept an answer to ANY of my questions. Not too much of a problem until this one cropped up. [How to reset Shotwell to its original state](https://askubuntu.com/questions/188081/how-to-reset-shotwell-to-its-original-state) The answer is flawless, easy to understand and works properly. It needs to be accepted, but my link is dead.

Comment: Can you tell us which answers you're having trouble accepting?

Comment: What browser are you using? It takes a few seconds for them to go through for me, even on a fast connection. Also, try using the mobile site with the [mobile] link at the bottom. It works file on computers.

Comment: It fails on Firefox and Chrome. Opera seems to work weirdly enough though!